# ArangoDB - IN operator very slow

Tags: indexing, database-performance, arangodb

I have some performance issues to use the `IN` operator in ArangoDB.

Briefly, I have an array of computed (at runtime) ids, coming from a splitting function, and I want to get only the selected elements of the Collection and, after that, collect or filter other data.

Here you can find the **AQL Query**:

```
LET toInclude = SPLIT('Collection/1,Collection/2,Collection/3', ',')

FOR result IN Collection
  FILTER result._id IN toInclude  
  COLLECT property = result.property 
  WITH COUNT INTO count
return  {property, count}
```

The elements in the array `toInclude` can be 300000+, and the query can spend more than 10 minutes to do the job.

The `split` - function finishes in 3sec, the `property` field is indexed, so the problem is in the `IN` operator.

What can I do to solve this performances issues?

Thank you very much!

Daniele

Comment: Looking at your `SPLIT` - your strings don't contain the character you use to split them? If you remove the `COLLECT` part of the query, does this change the performance?

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo error in the AQL, that now i'm going to fix: 
`LET toInclude = SPLIT('Collection/1,Collection/2,Collection/3')`

About removing `COLLECT`, no changes in the performance issues

Comment: if you use [explain](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/Optimizer.html), does it show whether the query is using an index?

Comment: `Indexes used: 
Id   Type      Collection    Unique   Sparse   Selectivity Est.   Fields   Ranges
 11   primary   SinistroEss   true     false            100.00 %   `_key`   [ `_id` == toInclude ]`

Without IN operator, it takes 0.2s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the query with 500,000 string entries in `toInclude` on a collection of 100,000 documents.

It indeed took very long to complete with 2.7. Execution time was around 4xx seconds. The query spends a lot of time evaluating the `FILTER`s `IN` operator there. In fact the `FILTER` condition will be evaluated for each document found. This will do around 100,000 x 500,000 / 2 comparisons with the data I used.

In 2.8 the same query takes around 2.7 seconds using the same data, so the problem seems to not occur there. There have been lots of optimizer changes in 2.8, and the one that's responsible for the speedup is that the `IN` expression will be evaluated directly in the index. The `FILTER` will be optimized away there.

So one fix will be to use ArangoDB 2.8 when it's available (currently it's in beta).

Another fix would be to improve the optimizer to detect that the right-hand side of the `IN` is const in the query so it can sort the result and can do `IN` using a binary search (logarithmic instead of linear complexity). But that's not yet available.

A workaround for 2.7 is to compute the `IN` list separately and insert it into the query as an array already. That way the `IN` list will be a constant value and the optimizer will be able to pre-sort it so it can use a binary search. However this requires the `SPLIT` operation to be performed outside of/before the original query.

**update**: in 2.8 there is now an additional optimizer rule to pre-sort `IN` list values for cases like the above and others. This enables the `IN` operator to use a binary search, with logarithmic complexity instead of linear complexity that it had for some cases. This change will be included in 2.8 beta2.

Comment: Thank you very much stj!

I wonder me how much stable is the beta, because in january we have to release a software with arangodb and I need the fix with IN operator. Otherwise, I have to rewrite the logic of this part of the software. 

Can I install the beta version with also the stable version in the linux server?   Must I only change the port of the DB?

Thank you again.

Daniele

Comment: It depends on your installation method. The packages usually replace older packages. You could however create a [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) and install the beta packages in there. If you're running debian/ubuntu, you may find [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) usefull.

Comment: We plan to release a new 2.8 beta this week. Regarding stability: the new beta will be much more stable than the previous one, but it will still be a beta and it's not recommended for production yet.